# Laravel 7 - Undefined variable: response

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

I am getting an undefined variable error, I don't know what the issue is, can anyone help me with this?

I have tried several alternatives, nothing seems to work, the values from the controller are just not passing into the javascript in my view.

Any solutions?

PaymentController.php:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Razorpay\Api\Api;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;

class PaymentController extends Controller
{
    public function initiate(Request $request)
    {
        $receiptid = Str::random(20);

        $amount = '5000';

        $api = new Api(env('RAZORPAY_KEY'), env('RAZORPAY_SECRET'));

        $order  = $api->order->create([
            'receipt'         => $receiptid,
            'amount'          => $amount * 100,
            'currency'        => 'INR',
        ]);

        $response = [
            'orderId' => $order['id'],
            'razorpayId' => env('RAZORPAY_KEY'),
            'amount' => $amount * 100,
            'currency' => 'INR',
            'name' => 'Test Corp',
            'user_name' => Auth::user()->name,
            'email' => Auth::user()->email,
            'contact' => 9999999999,
            'address' => 'Test Address',
            'description' => 'Registration Fee',
        ];

        return view('home', compact('response'));
    }
}
```

home.blade.php

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">Payments</div>
                <div class="card-body">
                    @if (session('status'))
                    <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
                        {{ session('status') }}
                    </div>
                    @endif
                        Pay the registration fee to complete your registration!
                    <br><br>
                    <div>
                        <button id="rzp-button1">Pay Now</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection

@section('js')
<script src="https://checkout.razorpay.com/v1/checkout.js"></script>
<script>
    var options = {
        "key": "{{ env('RAZORPAY_KEY') }}",
        "amount": "{{ $response['amount'] }}",
        "currency": "{{ $response['currency'] }}",
        "name": "{{ $response['name'] }}",
        "description": "{{ $response['description'] }}",
        "image": "img/eletter.png",
        "order_id": "{{ $response['orderId'] }}",
        "handler": function(response) {
            alert(response.razorpay_payment_id);
            alert(response.razorpay_order_id);
            alert(response.razorpay_signature)
        },
        "prefill": {
            "name": "{{ $response['user_name'] }}",
            "email": "{{ $response['email'] }}",
            "contact": "{{ $response['contact'] }}"
        },
        "notes": {
            "address": "{{ $response['address'] }}"
        },
        "theme": {
            "color": "#528FF0"
        }
    };
    var rzp1 = new Razorpay(options);
    document.getElementById('rzp-button1').onclick = function(e) {
        rzp1.open();
        e.preventDefault();
    }
</script>
@endsection
```

Routes - Web.php

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Auth::routes(['verify' => true]);

Route::get('home', 'HomeController@index');

Route::post('home', 'PaymentController@initiate');
```

**Here is the [StackTrace](https://flareapp.io/share/47qQ0A7W)**

Comment: Please start by showing us ALL the error message, it should have a filename and a line number as part of it

Comment: Hi, I have updated my question, please check. Added the **stack trace** at the bottom.

Comment: Just to confirm. the view you shared is actually `home.blade.php` (not view.blade.php as the question says) correct? And also you are doing a **POST** to the URL `http://mywebsite.com/home` when you get this error

Comment: @apokryfos, yes, I have updated my question.

Comment: Yes, @apokryfos is right. Please post the code of home.blade.php here.

Comment: You have error in home.blade.php.
At the time of loading of your home.blade.php, $response varaible is not defined.

Comment: can you suggest a solution? @Md Shahbaz Ahmad

Comment: Yes I have updated my answer. You may check, if any problem occurs, please ask in comment.

Comment: @Md Shahbaz Ahmad, thanks a lot for this, `$(document).ready(function(){ });` solved another issue I was having with executing the javascript, everything works fine now, thanks a bunch! I have also upvoted your answer and it's recorded but not displayed due to less reputation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is on your **route**. 
On your route, in **GET** response of `/home` you are using `HomeController@index` not `PaymentController@initiate`

```
Route::get('home', 'HomeController@index'); // you need to define $response here too
Route::post('home', 'PaymentController@initiate');
```

So only in post method you get the `$response` variable

I think you want something like :

```php
// Route::get('home', 'HomeController@index');
Route::get('home', 'PaymentController@initiate');
Route::post('home', 'PaymentController@initiateAction');
```

Answer (score 0):

In home.blade.php, make a form for post operations and remove the script tags.

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">Payments</div>
                <div class="card-body">
                    @if (session('status'))
                    <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
                        {{ session('status') }}
                    </div>
                    @endif
                        Pay the registration fee to complete your registration!
                    <br><br>
                    <div>
                      <form action="{{ route('home') }}" method="POST">
                        @csrf
                        <button id="rzp-button1" type="submit">Pay Now</button>
                      </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

Make another page called payment.blade.php

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">Payments</div>
                <div class="card-body">
                    Your message to be displayed for payment process
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection

@section('js')
<script src="https://checkout.razorpay.com/v1/checkout.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    var options = {
        "key": "{{ env('RAZORPAY_KEY') }}",
        "amount": "{{ $response['amount'] }}",
        "currency": "{{ $response['currency'] }}",
        "name": "{{ $response['name'] }}",
        "description": "{{ $response['description'] }}",
        "image": "img/eletter.png",
        "order_id": "{{ $response['orderId'] }}",
        "handler": function(response) {
            alert(response.razorpay_payment_id);
            alert(response.razorpay_order_id);
            alert(response.razorpay_signature)
        },
        "prefill": {
            "name": "{{ $response['user_name'] }}",
            "email": "{{ $response['email'] }}",
            "contact": "{{ $response['contact'] }}"
        },
        "notes": {
            "address": "{{ $response['address'] }}"
        },
        "theme": {
            "color": "#528FF0"
        }
    };
    var rzp1 = new Razorpay(options);
    rzp1.open();
    
});
</script>
@endsection
```

And at PaymentController.php

```
return view('payment', compact('response'));
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Md Shahbaz Ahmad, I have already tried this, still getting same error.

Comment: Maybe its an Authentication issue, but I don't know how to get around that in here.

Comment: `view('home', compact('var'))`, `view('home', ['var' => $var])`, `view('home')->with($var)` and `view('home')->with(['var' => $var])` are all syntactically acceptable ways of passing data from a Controller to a view. @MdShahbazAhmad You can suggest an alternative in a comment, but typically, this doesn't serve as an answer.

Comment: @Md Shahbaz Ahmad, thanks a lot for this, `$(document).ready(function(){ });` solved another issue I was having with executing the javascript, everything works fine now, thanks a bunch!

Comment: I have upvoted the answer but unfortunately, I have less than 15 reputation so stackoverflow says it was recorded, and I have also clicked thanks. :)

Comment: It's okay. @rv_100. I am happy :) that somehow your problem is solved. Vote doesn't matters, happiness matters. Happy coding.

Comment: Ur a saviour :)